# need to create an autoscaling group with encrypted EBS volume with Customer kms key

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-cdk, amazon-ebs

using AWS CDK, I need to create an autoscaling with encrypted volume with customer KMS key, I know that I can do this by using a launch template but I did not found in the documentation how to create the launch template and how to create the autoscaling group with this one.

I found just this constructor method "autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup"

```
autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(self, "my-app",
                                vpc=vpc,
                                vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(                                              
                                   subnets=[
                                      ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self,"asg_subnetAz1",subnet_az1_id), 
                                      ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self, "asg_subnetAz2", subnet_az2_id)
                                    ]
                                 ),
                                instance_type=ec2.InstanceType( instance_type_identifier=ec2_type),                                              
                                machine_image=linux_ami,
                                desired_capacity=1,
                                min_capacity=1,
                                max_capacity=1,
                                security_group=sg_asg,
                                block_devices=[
                                  autoscaling.BlockDevice(
                                     device_name="/dev/sda1", 
                                     volume=autoscaling.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(
                                            volume_size=ebs_volume_size, 
                                            delete_on_termination=delete, 
                                            encrypted=True, 
                                            volume_type=autoscaling.EbsDeviceVolumeType.GP2
                                      )
                                  )
                                ],
                               user_data=ec2.UserData.custom(user_data_ec2), 
                               role=self.ec2_role
)
```

it is working fine but in block_devides parameter I can not specify the customer key.

have you any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this perhaps could help another one.
to create the autoscaling with custom key 2 ways:

- Create a launch template where you can specify the KMS key to encrypt the EBS volume and then create ASG with this launch template.
- or just create the asg without encryption and change the account setting to force the encryption of every new ebs volume with the CMK. this is the easiest way.